# Why is my keyboard shortcut option+command+\ mapping to command+c?

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, keybindings

It's the weirdest thing, all of a sudden on macOS Catalina when I try to use my 1password shortcut <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> it for some reason gets mapped to <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. I checked here: http://keyboardchecker.com and it really weird that the <kbd>c</kbd> key gets pressed when I am literally typing <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>. Here's a video:

[image: keyboard video]

What might be causing this??

Comment: Do you have any tools like Karabiner installed ? @Raymond Also check for any custom shortcuts defined in Keyboard preferences.

Comment: @ankii at the time, no I did not have it installed. I just tried installing it and am still running into the same issue...

Comment: Was anyone able to resolve this? The answer on the original question did not resolve the issue for me.